# jQuery/JS: Array reference fine on one line, TypeError: variable undefined the next

Tags: jquery, arrays, typeerror

I don't understand why I keep getting the error `TypeError: selected_tiles[count] is undefined` on the console.log line (and any time I try to use it after) when it works just fine in the if statement before.

```
 //fyi, tiles are divs
var selected_tiles = $("[id^=choice-]");
   //remove deleted buttons (nested divs) from selected_tiles array
for(var count = 0; count<selected_tiles.length; count++){
  if (selected_tiles[count]['id'].substr((selected_tiles[count]['id'].length)-4, selected_tiles[count]['id'].length) == '-del'){
    selected_tiles.splice(count, 1);
  }
  console.log(selected_tiles[count]['id']);
 //was going to put an if statement here to remove the array elements with unselected in their attributes (a data html tag)
}
```

Comment: When asking for help, **please** take the time to indent your code readably.

Answer (score 0):

(At the very end of the answer is a one-liner that replaces that entire loop.)

Because you sometimes delete entries from `selected_tiles`, so if you delete the **last** entry, `selected_tiles[count]` will be beyond the end of the <s>array</s> jQuery set, giving you `undefined`, and you can't access `['id']` on `undefined`.

```
//fyi, tiles are divs
var selected_tiles = $("[id^=choice-]");
//remove deleted buttons (nested divs) from selected_tiles array
for (var count = 0; count < selected_tiles.length; count++) {
    if (selected_tiles[count]['id'].substr((selected_tiles[count]['id'].length) - 4, selected_tiles[count]['id'].length) == '-del') {
        selected_tiles.splice(count, 1);       // <== Deletes an entry
    }
    console.log(selected_tiles[count]['id']);  // <== Assumes count is still valid
    //was going to put an if statement here to remove the array elements with unselected in their attributes (a data html tag)
}
```

If you delete the entry, don't try to access it after deleting it; perhaps using `else`:

```
//fyi, tiles are divs
var selected_tiles = $("[id^=choice-]");
//remove deleted buttons (nested divs) from selected_tiles array
for (var count = 0; count < selected_tiles.length; count++) {
    if (selected_tiles[count]['id'].substr((selected_tiles[count]['id'].length) - 4, selected_tiles[count]['id'].length) == '-del') {
        selected_tiles.splice(count, 1);
    } else {                                   // <== else
        console.log(selected_tiles[count]['id']);
    }
}
```

---

Side note: It's generally a poor idea to repeatedly look up the same property on an object, as that code is doing on `selected_tiles[count]` and `selected_tiles[count]['id']`. Instead, use a variable:

```
var id;
//fyi, tiles are divs
var selected_tiles = $("[id^=choice-]");
//remove deleted buttons (nested divs) from selected_tiles array
for (var count = 0; count < selected_tiles.length; count++) {
    tile = selected_tiles[count]['id']; // or `selected_tiles[count].id`, of course
    if (id.substr(id.length - 4, id.length) == '-del') {
        selected_tiles.splice(count, 1);
    } else {
        console.log(id);
    }
}
```

---

Side note 2: You're using an **undocumented** feature of jQuery. jQuery objects are not documented as having a `splice` function. They do have one, for internal use, but it's not documented, and that means it could disappear between one dot release and the next.

In this case, you might consider using `filter` instead:

```
var selected_tiles = $("[id^=choice-]").filter(function(index, entry) {
    if (this.id.substr(id.length - 4, this.id.length) == '-del') {
        return false;
    }
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

Or just `:not`:

```
var selected_tiles = $("[id^=choice-]:not([id$=-del])");
```